# How do I define global names?

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python, but I'm having some trouble making a sort of text adventure game because of global names, here's my code.

```
def startcave():
    print "You awake in an dark cave. You can't remember your past, but you need to find a way out. You feel hungry, although tired."
    print "Would you like to delve deeper via a cave passage, or look for a way out in this room?"
    answer = raw_input("Do you go -Deeper-, -Search-, or -Rest-?").lower()
    if answer == "Deeper" or answer == "deeper":
        lowcave1()
    elif answer == "Search" or answer == "search":
        searchcave()
    elif answer == "Rest" or answer == "rest":
        caverest()
    else:
        print "You must either say -Deeper- or -Search-"
        startcave()

startcave()

def lowcave1():
    print "You go deeper into the cave, walking down a steadily reclining corridor for some time, you have lost track of time."
    print "There is a large ledge before you. You can jump down, but there is no way back up."
    print "The cave may be dangerous, and you could end up being trapped. Do you turn back?"
    answer = raw_input("Do you -Jump- or -Turn back-?").lower()
    if answer == "Jump" or answer == "jump":
        lowcave2()
    elif answer == "Turn back":
        caverest2()

lowcave1()
```

If I answer "Deeper", this error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\Cavestuff.py", line 15, in <module>
    startcave()
  File "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\Cavestuff.py", line 6, in startcave
    lowcave1()
NameError: global name 'lowcave1' is not defined
```

Comment: What precisely is the problem? Is there an error message that's being generated, or is the code behaving unexpectedly? Could you edit your question to include more details?

Comment: "Hello Mr. Mechanic, I'm having *some trouble* with my car. Here is the whole car, please fix it."

Comment: Off topic but, your call to startcave is not nice... Use a loop instead, that will avoid problems (imagine if the player keeps typing wrong answers, 1 000 000 times).

Comment: I'm not sure where you want to use global variables here. There aren't any, and I can't see any place you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define all functions before calling them

```
def startcave():
    print "You awake in an dark cave. You can't remember your past, but you need to find a way out. You feel hungry, although tired."
    print "Would you like to delve deeper via a cave passage, or look for a way out in this room?"
    answer = raw_input("Do you go -Deeper-, -Search-, or -Rest-?").lower()
    if answer == "Deeper" or answer == "deeper":
        lowcave1()
    elif answer == "Search" or answer == "search":
        searchcave()
    elif answer == "Rest" or answer == "rest":
        caverest()
    else:
        print "You must either say -Deeper- or -Search-"
        startcave()

def lowcave1():
    print "You go deeper into the cave, walking down a steadily reclining corridor for some time, you have lost track of time."
    print "There is a large ledge before you. You can jump down, but there is no way back up."
    print "The cave may be dangerous, and you could end up being trapped. Do you turn back?"
    answer = raw_input("Do you -Jump- or -Turn back-?").lower()
    if answer == "Jump" or answer == "jump":
        lowcave2()
    elif answer == "Turn back":
        caverest2()

startcave()

lowcave1()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the global keyword to indicate you mean to use a global variable.

```
foo = 123

def bar():
    global foo
    print(foo)
```

Comment: @Maxime the global variable in this example would be 'foo'. As far as I understood, the 'global' keyword indicates that the variable is global, thus the line 'global foo'.

Comment: @dirtdiver24 I obviously meant, in OP's code. I understand that code, thanks ;).

Comment: Attempting to make lowcave1() a global variable. Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: @user2788215 I'm not sure making a function into a global variable is really what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you should use `global`.

```
a = 1
print '1: ', a # Prints 1: 1

def f1():
  a = 2
  print '2: ', a

f1() # Prints 2: 2

print '3: ', a # Prints 3: 1

def f2():
  global a
  a = 3
  print '4: ', a

f2() # Prints 4: 3

print '5: ', a # Prints 5: 3
```